# a question about gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus, gradient-flows

> Let $f(x,y)=\ln\|\mathbf r\|$ where $\mathbf r=x\mathbf i+y\mathbf j$. Show that $\nabla f=\frac{\mathbf r}{\|\mathbf r\|^2}$.

I attempt to calculate $\nabla\mathbf r$. But I have no idea how to calculate a vector's gradient. Can anybody help me?

Comment: From the definitions,  and assuming you meant to say $\mathbf r = x\mathbf i+y\mathbf j$, we have  $f(x,y)=\ln \sqrt {x^2+y^2}$, no?

Comment: oh sorry. I forgot the definition. Now I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\vec \nabla f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \hat i +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \hat j + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \hat k $$

$$\vec r = x \hat i + y\hat j $$ so $$||\vec r || = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
so
$$\ln||\vec r|| = \ln\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
so
$$\vec \nabla \Big(\ln \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\Big)$$
$$ = \frac{\partial \Big(\ln \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\Big)}{\partial x}\hat i + \frac{\partial \Big(\ln \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\Big)}{\partial y}\hat + \frac{\partial \Big(\ln \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\Big)}{\partial z}\hat k$$
$$ = \frac{2x \cdot \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\hat i + \frac{2y \cdot \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\hat j + \frac{2z \cdot \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\hat k$$
$$ = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} \hat i + \frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \hat j + \frac{z}{x^2+y^2} \hat k$$
$$ = \frac{1}{x^2+y^2} (x \hat i + y\hat j + z\hat k)$$ 
$$ = \frac{1}{||\vec r||^2} \vec r$$
$$ = \frac{\vec r}{||\vec r||^2}$$ as required

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you so much!

Comment: no problem, if thats all you required feel free to upvote and indicate it's the answer  by clicking the green arrow :)